# Random "Unexpected end of Zlib input stream" exception when trying to gunzip files

Tags: java, linux, gzip, eof

I have a class that is supposed to extract a given tar.gz file into a simple .tar file.
But for some files this exception is thrown :

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

The method managing the extraction look like this :

```
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream( baseInputStream );
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( destinationFile );
while ( ( count = gzipInputStream.read( data, 0, BUFFER ) ) != -1 )
{
    fileOutputStream.write( data, 0, count );
}
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
gzipInputStream.close();
```

The strange thing is that the exception is thrown for some files and sometimes it does not, but I can't figure out why... :(

Am I missing something ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Bad/damaged input file?

Comment: I do not think so, the original .tar.gz file is valid. But for a given .tar.gz file that crash, the destination extracted .tar file has always a different size which means it crashs on different times on each execution...

Comment: How do you get baseInputStream? That is not included in your code. Plus I would suggest using try-with-resources for the streams to ensure they are closed properly on exceptions. It is a good habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to a concurrent access to the file by another thread.